# Jtable Hide some columns

Tags: java, jtable

How to make a table from some, but not all columns in an object? This is the desired output:

```
 ID|Author|Messages
 ----------------------------
 2 |Alice | My first message   
 5 |Alice | My second message
 6 |Bob   | Hello
```

This is the object.

```
      private String[] columnNames
            = {"ID","Author", "HideThis", "Messages"};

    private Object[][] data = {
        {"2", "Alice", "Hide this", "My first message"},
        {"5", "Alice", "Hide this", "My second message"},
        {"6", "Bob", "Hide this", "Hello"}
    };
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
```

Do I have to create a new data object and copy only relevant columns or is there a way to say columnSetHidden(2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(ProcessArray(data,1),columnNames);

 public Object[][] ProcessArray(Object[][] arr,int colindex) {

            List points = Arrays.asList(arr);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                   points.remove(arr[i][colindex]);
                }
             }
             Object[][] returnData = (Object[][]) points.toArray();
             return returnData;

        }
```

theres no Api specification in `DefaultTableModel` to remove a `column`, but you can `customize` your 2d array and remove the column you need. and then pass the processed array to the constructor of the `DefaultTableModel`. However you still need to change the column names.